# Change individual inline styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, lets say i have three images with the same css class.
Its easy enough to change the style of this class via javascript (document.getElementById etc), but is there a way to change the inline style of *one* of those images using pure javascript.

The script will go in a for loop, so that each time it runs a *different* inline style will be applied to each *image*.

To do this i need to make a distinction between the three images

Comment: um, getElementById *will* change only one. Usually I see people asking how to do this the other way around!

Comment: how do i make a distinction between the three images though, i intend to put the script in a for loop so that it will change the z-index of each of the images making only one appear at a time?

Comment: Why can't you assign them IDs?

Comment: lets say you have 20 images, you then have to make 17 more ids for those images, i want a fluid flexible system that lets me add or remove images as i please without having to add more ids or remove some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style) contains one JavaScript property for each CSS property. Example:

```
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
img1.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
```